# Justification for the Taylor series of the complex sinc function $f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}&:z\neq 0 \\ 1&:z = 0\end{cases}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Define $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ as $f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}&:z\neq 0 \\\ 1&:z = 0\end{cases}$. It is easy to verify with the help of l'Hospital's rule that $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z) = 1$. In order to find the Taylor series of $f$ one might want to utilize the known form for $\sin(z)$ and just divide the series by $z$. Unfortunately my complex analysis skills are a bit rusty and I can't for the life of me remember/figure out a justification for this process. That is, given the definition of $f$ and the Taylor series of $\sin(z)$, with an infinite radius of convergence, how can we argue that the expansion of $f$ about $z = 0$ is that of $\sin(z)$ divided by $z$?

Edit: Regarding the limit of $f$ at the origin: $\sin(0) = 0, z = 0$ so that $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z} = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(\sin(z))'}{(z)'} = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\cos(z)}{1} = 1$.

Comment: How do you justify that $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}z=1$ using l'Hospital's rule?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos See the edited post.

Comment: So, you are usng the fact that, for each $z\in\Bbb C$, $\sin'(z)=\cos(z)$. Am I right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, that is right.

Comment: So, in particular, you know that $\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1$, right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes.

Comment: But $\sin'(0)$ *means* $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}z$. Therefore, your use of l'Hospital's rule is circular. You are using the fact that $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}z=1$ in order to prove that same statement.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah, that is true. I suppose that the proper way would be to use the squeeze theorem as in the real case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141045/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-cartesian-bear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and for any number $\lambda$, you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lambda a_n=\lambda\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$. So, in particular,\begin{align}\sin z&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\\&=z\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!},\end{align}and therefore$$z\ne0\implies\frac{\sin z}z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}.$$And, of course, if $z=0$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series defines an entire function $f$ by using the ratio test.  Sinc is also an entire function.

We can see that $zf(z)=\sin(z)$ for all $z$ by comparing their Taylor series.  So $f(z) = \textrm{sinc(z)}$ for all $z \neq 0$.  However, $f(0)=1$, so they are actually identically equal.  Two equal functions have identical Taylor series.